# How to add extra class with easepick

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Please Help! How to add "myCss" class for one date before bookedDates? (17 Aug and 17 Sep in my example). The idea is to paint a different color day before booked.
This is example code for which I am trying to do this:

```js
const DateTime = easepick.DateTime;
const bookedDates = [
    '18-08-2022', '19-08-2022', '20-08-2022', '18-09-2022', '19-09-2022', '20-09-2022',
].map(d => {
    if (d instanceof Array) {
        const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'DD-MM-YYYY');
        const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'DD-MM-YYYY');
        return [start, end];
    }
    return new DateTime(d, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
});
const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    css: [
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.0/dist/index.css',
        'https://easepick.com/css/demo_hotelcal.css',
    ],
    readonly: true,
    zIndex: 10,
    format: "DD MMM YYYY",
    readonly: false,
    plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
    RangePlugin: {
        tooltipNumber(num) {
            return num - 1;
        },
        locale: {
            one: 'night',
            other: 'nights',
        },
    },
    LockPlugin: {
        minDate: new Date(),
        minDays: 2,
        inseparable: true,
        filter(date, picked) {
            if (picked.length === 1) {
                const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
                return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
            }
            return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.0/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
<input readonly="readonly" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a *setup* option in easepick.create({ ... }):

> Before date

```
setup(picker) {
    picker.on('view', (event) => {
        const { view, target, date } = event.detail;
            if (view === 'CalendarDay') {
                const dayAfter = date.clone().add(1, 'day');

                if (
                  ! picker.options.LockPlugin.filter(date, picker.datePicked)
                  && picker.options.LockPlugin.filter(dayAfter, picker.datePicked)
                ) {
                    target.classList.add('myCss');
                }
            }
    });
},
```

> After date

```
setup(picker) {
    picker.on('view', (event) => {
        const { view, target, date } = event.detail;
            if (view === 'CalendarDay') {
                const dayBefore = date.clone().subtract(1, 'day');

                if (
                  picker.options.LockPlugin.filter(dayBefore, picker.datePicked)
                  && ! picker.options.LockPlugin.filter(date, picker.datePicked)
                ) {
                    target.classList.add('myCss');
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! If it's not difficult - write please how to do the same after bookedDates

Comment: Updated! Check it out.